# Should cross-browser and cross-platform be performed for testing network calls from a website?

Tags: javascript, web-application, coverage, cross-browser-testing, web

My team is implementing Adobe Analytics on a web site.

We have three layers where it should be tested.

1. Adobe Data Layer.

The required variables and their values are added to an object handled by a script added to the page.

2. Network call.

Data added to the Adobe Data Layer is sent to the Adobe Analytics server through a network call.

3. Adobe Analytics platform.

Validation of data on the Adobe Analytics site.

All of these 3 layers are not related to the layouts of pages from which data should be sent.
Thus I have a question should I perform cross-browser testing? How do browsers affect network calls and javascript logic on pages?
Same question for cross-platform testing like Windows/MacOS/Android.
I think it has an even lesser impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser is just a engine ( software ) that can execute javascript in it :

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/all-possible-ways-of-making-an-api-call-in-plain-javascript-c0dee3c11b8b

this is a good article that define how to do network calls from front . IF you check each implementation it mention browser support

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

[image]

You can see for each javascript function there are supported browser list mentioned.

So it is important to do cross browser testing as backed call module support varies according to the browser used.

Comment: I see there is a separation for desktop and mobile so I assume there is a difference in that. But is there a difference between for example Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Mac?

Comment: @seeker001 there shouldn't be but as all software chrome can be working weird in different OS . So it could be a chrome bug but it might affect your product